# Cómo habilitar y deshabilitar un campo en funcion de otros campos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por un lado estoy intentando encontrar la forma de habilitar los campos "Detalle del cierre" (id="fe685" name="009002005"), "Incentivo" (id="fe690" name="009002011") y "Observaciones" (id="fe691" name="009002012") cuando hago clic en el select (name="cmb3" id="cmb3) y pongo "Contestar" y deshabilitar el campo "Fecha de reagenda" (name="009002009" for="fe689") cuando se cumplen esas condiciones. Y por otro lado que suceda al revés, cuando hago clic en el select (name="cmb3" id="cmb3) y pongo "Reagendar", que se deshabiliten el resto y se habilite "Fecha de reagenda". Lo he intentado como muestro, pero solo se deshabilitan cuando hago clic en el select reagendar, cuando pongo contestar, el campo "Fecha de reagenda" no se deshabilita.
Si me podéis ayudar.... por favor!
Gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery.datetimepicker2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="prettify-1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker2.full.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form " id="form77">
  <div class="layout container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement14" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label for="pais">Acción</label>
              <select name="cmb3" id="cmb3" required="required">
                                    <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                   
                                    <option value="PROCEDE">Contestar</option>
                                    <option value="NO PROCEDE">Reagendar</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement5" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label class="elq-label " for="fe685">Detalle del cierre
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="field-control-wrapper">
                    <select class="elq-item-select" id="fe685" name="009002005" style="width:100%;" data-value="">
                      <option value="Blanco">Blanco
                      </option>
                      <option value="Precio">Precio
                      </option>
                      <option value="Producto y coberturas">Producto y coberturas
                      </option>
                      <option value="Sólo interés precio">Sólo interés precio
                      </option>
                      <option value="Riesgo prohibido/BNS">Riesgo prohibido/BNS
                      </option>
                      <option value="Riesgo prohibido/VCH">Riesgo prohibido/VCH
                      </option>
                      <option value="Riesgo prohibido/SINIESTRALIDAD">Riesgo prohibido/SINIESTRALIDAD
                      </option>
                      <option value="Riesgo prohibido/EVALUACIÓN DE CLIENTE">Riesgo prohibido/EVALUACIÓN DE CLIENTE
                      </option>
                      <option value="Duplicado">Duplicado
                      </option>
                      <option value="Reenvío Mediador">Reenvío Mediador
                      </option>
                      <option value="Cliente Mediado">Cliente Mediado
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement11" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label class="elq-label " id="fe690">Incentivo
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="field-control-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="elq-item-input" id="fe690" name="009002011" value="" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement12" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label class="elq-label " for="fe691">Observaciones
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="field-control-wrapper">
                    <textarea class="elq-item-textarea" id="fe691" style="width:100%;" name="009002012">
                    </textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement9" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label class="elq-label " for="fe689">Fecha de reagenda
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="input-group date">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="fe689">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="009002009" value="" style="width:100%;">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-layout-col">
        <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div id="formElement13" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div>
                    <input type="Submit" class="submit-button-style " value="Submit" id="fe674">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 <script>
        $("#fe689").datetimepicker({minDate: moment()});
    </script>
<script>
                                // traemos de DOM el select mediante su id



var select1 = document.getElementById('cmb3');
var select7 = document.getElementById('fe685');
var select13 = document.getElementById('fe689');
// le ponemos un evento que se ejecuta al cambiar la
// opción al primer select
select1.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
// si el select 1 esta en el índice 1 (PROCEDE)
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select7.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select7.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select7.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select7.disabled=true;
    }
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 2) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select13.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select13.disabled=true;
    }
});

var select1 = document.getElementById('cmb3');
var select12 = document.getElementById('fe690');
var select13 = document.getElementById('fe689');
// le ponemos un evento que se ejecuta al cambiar la
// opción al primer select
select1.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
// si el select 1 esta en el índice 1 (PROCEDE)
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select12.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select12.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select12.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitmos el select 2
      select12.disabled=true;
    }
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 2) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select13.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select13.disabled=true;
    }
});

var select1 = document.getElementById('cmb3');
var select14 = document.getElementById('fe691');
var select13 = document.getElementById('fe689');
// le ponemos un evento que se ejecuta al cambiar la
// opción al primer select
select1.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
// si el select 1 esta en el índice 1 (PROCEDE)
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select14.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select14.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select14.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select14.disabled=true;
    }
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 2) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select13.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select13.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select13.disabled=true;
    }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero uses jQuery en vez de document.getElementById, colocar nombres más significativos a cada elemento; y usar value en vez de selectedIndex. Realizando esto podrás leer mejor tu código y te será más fácil establecer la lógica que requiere; si lo checas excepto al selecionar contestar también se desahabilita (por usar selectedIndex).

Comment: @RobertoLeOr ¿porqué recomiendas usar JQuery? Sólo porque sea más cómodo para unos no significa que sea una panacea para todos. Yo podría recomendar *no usar* JQuery, y mi apreciación sería tan válida como la tuya. En cuanto al resto concuerdo contigo, nombres de variables más adecuadas y correcto uso de las propiedades de los objetos del DOM. Tener `select1` a `selectN` hace difícil entender cuando hay más de 2 elementos de tipo `select`. Por otro lado, necesitas crear una tabla de la verdad para ver el corto circuito que necesitas y así poder programarlo. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @MauricioContreras ; no "recomendé" yo "sugerí" (para mi es distinto). Como bien mencionas por comididad; hoy día es el que uso; tambien pudo ser otros; adicionalmente que ese como otros se encargan de hacer transparente ciertas cosas "sin importar" el navegador.